# Basic Objective-C typecasting question

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting, nsstring

Consider the following code:

```
if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])  {
   NSString *s = [(NSString *)obj stringByAppendingString:@"xyzzy"];
}
```

I'm a bit confused here. The `if` statement checks whether or not `obj` is of the `NSString` class. If it is, it assigns the object and an appended string to `NSString *s`, do I understand this correctly? If so, why would you still cast it to `(NSString *)`? 
Doesn't the `if` statement already check for that and doesn't that make the typecasting unnecessary?

Wouldn't it be perfectly fine to just say:

`NSString *s = obj stringByAppendingString:@"xyzzy"];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that it is exceedingly atypical to do `isKindOfClass:` based coding.  It generally indicates a shoddy architecture if you don't know what type any given object reference actually is.

Comment: I see. This was an example from the CS193P slides; I'll keep your comment in mind! Thanks.

Comment: @bbum I wouldn't say so. There are many legit use cases where `isKindOfClass:` makes sense. E.g. some times a method needs to allow the caller to supply an argument of an unknown class, in which case you would use the `id` "class" in the method definition and rely on `isKindOfClass:` to handle the different types accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasWatson For things like XML parsers where the next node's type is only known at parse time? Sure.   In general, a parameter of type `id` indicates a loosely specified architecture and moves a whole slew of problems from compile time type checking to runtime exceptions.   Heavy use of `isKindOfClass:` is indicative of a fragile codebase that will be more costly to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how `obj` is defined. If it is `id obj` then no casting is needed, but if it was defined as `NSObject *obj` the cast *is* necessary to suppress the compiler warning that `stringByAppendingString:` is not defined on `NSObject`. The cast is not needed to make the code work at runtime, it only tells the compiler the "correct" type so it can tell whether the method should exist on the object.

The reason why the cast isn't needed for `id` is because `id` means *"an object of any type"*, while `NSObject *` means *"an object of type NSObject"*.

Comment: I think I understand when it comes to `id`. However, how would an object defined as `NSObject *obj` pass the if clause here? It's testing for `NSString class`, right? Or would it pass because `NSString` inherits from `NSObject`?

Comment: `obj` may contain a `NSString *` because `NSString` is derived from `NSObject`. But the compiler does only know about the `NSObject` methods at the time of the `if` (`isKindOfClass:` is one of those methods defined in `NSObject`), it doesn't yet know about the additional methods that were defined in the `NSString` class. The `if` now checks whether the object in `obj` is more than just a `NSObject`, it checks whether it's actually a `NSString`. If the check is passed we know it's a `NSString`, and now you need to tell the compiler to treat it like that with the cast.